# How to install cross_sim==0.2.0 in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am struggling to install a cross_sim==0.2.0 in Python (colab). I face an error like this

> (Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cross_sim==0.2.0 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for cross_sim==0.2.0).

How to solve the issue?

I have been trying `!pip install cross-sim`, and `!pip install --upgrade https://github.com/sandialabs/cross-sim` and `!git clone https://github.com/sandialabs/cross-sim`, and so on none of the processes were working. how to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you clarify something? Is the same error present when you try `!git clone https://github.com/sandialabs/cross-sim`? I don't usually use github, but maybe try `!gh repo clone sandialabs/cross-sim` or `!git repo clone https://github.com/sandialabs/cross-sim.git`? The package `cross-sim` doesn't seem to be available on pip.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. However, above, you mentioned some code that doesn't solve the issues. The below codes have shown some errors.                                                                                                                 import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pkg_resources

datapath = pkg_resources.resource_filename(".cross_sim","data")

from cross_sim import Backprop, Parameters
from cross_sim import plot_tools as PT
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Comment: Yeah ok... so you might have to reinstall Python... I think you may have a problem with PATH or the file system within your `python.exe` folder, wherever that may be. It appears that `python.exe` can't access the folder `Libs`, not even builtins. Have you by any chance changed the location of `python.exe`? I think `pip` can find where to install the package, but it can't find the `python.exe` executable. I may be wrong.

Comment: I have tried downgrading the Python version. Moreover, I used to try the Conda version and install all the required version. **Windows 10 using Python 3.7.6**  CrossSim requires the following Python packages:

Comment: Any lucky reinstalling python? Maybe not practical, but easiest solution. Also do you know how to check your PATH variable?

Comment: @Anony Mous, I appreciate your help. I have tried reinstalling the required Python version. Yes, I know how to check the path. The major problem is I have downloaded the cross-sim package from GitHub; the folder doesn't have the setup.py file. They mentioned that Cross-Sim needs the following Python packages Windows 10 (Python 3.7.6). 'TensorFlow 2.4.1' (includes Keras 2.4.0), 'Numpy 1.20.3', 'SciPy 1.7.1', 'Pandas 1.3.3', 'MatPlotLib 3.4.3', 'OpenCV 4.5.4', 'Torchvision 0.11.1', and 'Larq 0.12.1'. After all installations, I still couldn't solve the error. Is there are any other options?

Comment: Have you read through the instructions on the github page? For example: `After cloning this repository, the following commands will fetch the submodules.

git submodule init
git submodule update --progress
This command downloads about 1.2GB of data for the two repositories (combined), which is then de-compressed. After cloning the submodules, you can test CrossSim Inference by running the following commands:

cd inference
python run_inference.py`

Comment: I appreciate your help; I can successfully install the cross-sim! I used the following codes.                                                                                                                              
!git clone https://github.com/sandialabs/cross-sim
!cd cross-sim
!git submodule init
!git submodule update --progress                                                                                                 !cd inference        and        !python run_inference.py

Comment: Great to hear! Happy coding!